# Что стоит обрабатывать Fatal exception или Caused by ... exception

Tags: java, android

Заинтересовал меня такой вопрос. В java есть возможность обрабатывать исключения во избежание краша программы. Если не вдаваться в детали можно сделать блок catch с обработкой общего класса Exception

```
catch (Exception e)
```

но это не очень хороший подход, ведь существует огромное множество подклассов исключений что позволяет более корректно обрабатывать их.
У меня в приложении возник эксепшен с таким стак трейсом:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.ster/activity.MainActivity}
 Raw Text
android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack (TaskStackBuilder.java:247)
android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack (TaskStackBuilder.java:226)
com.ster.manager.SterNotificationManager.showUserMessage (SterNotificationManager.java:40)
com.ster.service.SterGcmListenerService.handleUserMessage (SGcmListenerService.java:129)
com.ster.service.SterGcmListenerService.onMessageReceived (SGcmListenerService.java:82)
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzq (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzp (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run (Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:856)

Caused by android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException
android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo (ApplicationPackageManager.java:223)
android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName (NavUtils.java:301)
android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent (NavUtils.java:262)
android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack (TaskStackBuilder.java:240)
android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack (TaskStackBuilder.java:226)
com.ster.manager.SterNotificationManager.showUserMessage (SterNotificationManager.java:40)
com.ster.service.SterGcmListenerService.handleUserMessage (SterGcmListenerService.java:129)
com.ster.service.SterGcmListenerService.onMessageReceived (SterGcmListenerService.java:82)
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzq (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzp (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run (Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
```

И собственно вопрос заключается в том какое исключение в таких ситуациях стоит ловить?

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

или

> Caused by android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException

P.S.
Извиняюсь за свою необразованность. Буду признателен образованным разработчикам за развернутый ответ.

Comment: как ты думаешь, в этом случае `NameNotFoundException` поможет поймать `IllegalArgumentException` ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator я думаю, если бы я знал, я бы задавал такой вопрос :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему ловить Exception не очень хороший подход?
Все зависит от того, как ваша программа должна реагировать на разные типы ошибок. Например, если вы хотите при получении любого checked или unchecked exception, просто залоггировать его и продолжить работу, то это нормальный вариант.
Ловить частные исключения есть смысл, если на конкретный тип исключения, ваша программа сможет отреагировать. Например у вас в коде есть что-нибудь типа `StopApplicationException`, при получении которого она должна прекратить работу, а все остальные просто логгировать. В таком случае есть смысл ловить `StopApplicationException` в отдельном `catch` блоке, а все остальные в другом.
Для вашего случая, я бы сначала решил как вы будете реагировать на все исключения которые возможно будут выброшены.  Если хотите обрабатывать только `android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException`- ловите его (все остальные будут проброшены выше), если все, которые так или иначе могут произойти - то `Exception`

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае класс, который выдал исключение зависит так

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    java.lang.Throwable
       ↳    java.lang.Exception
           ↳    android.util.AndroidException
               ↳    android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException
```

вы сможете поймать его, если укажете `NameNotFoundException` и выше. конечно, чем выше, тем больше исключений попадут в ваш оператор `try-catch`

Доп материалы [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.NameNotFoundException.html#PackageManager.NameNotFoundException())